# /bin/zsh can't open script when it's run by launchd

Tags: macos, zsh, launchd

I have a very simple zsh script, that I want to run periodically using launchd. I decided to use the LaunchDaemons, because it seemed more versatile. I believe the process starts, because there is output in the path, defined in the `StandardErrorPath` key in the plist file.

The script looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
echo "hello"
```

And the plist file looks like this:

[image: Plist entries]

When I load the `launchd` process using

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/testplist.plist
```

there is no error message, but in the system.log there is an error message every time it tries to execute it. It varied a bit, but I consistently got an error:

> Service exited with abnormal code: 127

Also, every time an error 127 was added to the system log, a line was also added to the file specified in the plist as `StandardErrorPath`. The line was

> /bin/zsh: can't open input file: /Users/username/Downloads/zsh/test.zsh

What I tried:

- Changing the plist owner from my user, to root in the LaunchDaemons folder using `sudo chown root testplist.plist`
- Making an executable file from the zsh script using `chmod +x filename`
- Running the script in itself, with success (`/bin/zsh /Users/username/Downloads/zsh/test.zsh`)

One last thing, that may or may not be relevant, when I wrote my zsh script I changed the permission to 750, because that's what the tutorial said and without that it wouldn't run.

Text format of the plist:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>testplist</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/username/Downloads/zsh/stderr.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/username/Downloads/zsh/stdout.log</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/username/Downloads/zsh/test.zsh</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a _textual_ dump of the plist so we can test it ourselves without needing to retype? (The reasoning given in [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) applies).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're installing this as a _system_ daemon rather than a per-user agent?

Comment: If you _are_ going to be installing this as a daemon, you should use `UserName` or `UID`, and `GroupName` or `GID` to ensure that the script runs _as you_

Comment: I added the plist as text. For my actual zsh script, that I would want to run, it is important to be able to run without being logged in, and I saw somewhere that Daemons are good for that. Would I just add the UID and GID as a key to the plist?

Comment: (the daemon not having access to read the file with its source code -- when that file is installed in your home directory -- is one of the reasons I suspect that it's not running as the desired account)

Comment: (...and when you have it installed in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and don't include a UID in the plist, it would be very abnormal if it _did_ run with your personal UID).

Comment: I also think that, but I find it weird because it can write to files in the same directory.

Comment: Not necessarily, because stdin, stdout and stderr are hooked up _before_ a program is started. So it's perfectly reasonable for launchd to use root privileges to open those files, then drop those privileges before actual execution.

Comment: I'll try adding a UID (and GID) and see if it solves it

Comment: I'd also suggest moving the executable to somewhere like `/usr/local/bin` that's unambiguously world-readable.

Comment: Putting the zsh script to the folder you recommended, actually solved it (maybe the username had to be added as well). Thank you! Is it possible to change the permissions for the script, so it can be anywhere?

Comment: It's not just the permissions for the script itself that matter -- the _directories leading up to the script_ need to be traversed by the user that runs it., so if it's `/home/someone/bin/myscript`, permissions for `/home/someone/bin` and `/home/someone` are pertinent.

Comment: (Also, on Catalina and later MacOS has some extra restrictions on which processes can access which directories; that's its own thing, and I'd need to do some research to know how it impacts daemons).

Comment: Have you tried to move `zsh/test.zsh` into `/Users/username/tmp` ?